Use getRecord wire adapter to get a record’s data using junction id list names
I'm quite confused about a spec in the documentation of getRecord wire adapter.

fields — (Either fields or layoutTypes is required) A field or an array of fields to return. If the context user doesn’t have access to a field, an error is returned. If you’re not sure whether the context user has access to a field and you don’t want the request to fail if they don’t, use the optionalFields parameter.
Specify field names in the format ObjectApiName.FieldName or ObjectApiName.JunctionIdListName.

The last sentence is what isn't unclear and without examples. What is a junction id list name?
I initially supposed it was a reference to a relationship name, providing the possibility to return a list of children. However, trying Account.Contacts resulted in an error for invalid field.

INVALID_FIELD:
SELECT LastModifiedDate, Suffix, Contacts, FirstName, RecordTypeId
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:34
No such column 'Contacts' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."


See e.g. the answer to Can I create field with type JunctionIdList? that includes:

That field type is only available to relate activities to a select few standard objects

That statement is consistent with running this code:
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(MyCustomObject__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().childRelationships));

that returns that there are no JunctionIdList type fields:
  ...
}, {
  "cascadeDelete" : false,
  "childSObject" : "DocumentIntake__c",
  "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
  "field" : "Investment__c",
  "junctionIdListNames" : [ ],
  "junctionReferenceTo" : [ ],
  "relationshipName" : "DocumentIntakes__r",
  "restrictedDelete" : false
}, {
  ...

So stick to specifying using the ObjectApiName.FieldName format.
